# How to get selected CheckBoxes Value/Name in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, maui

I have a dynamic checkbox,

```
private async void GetOffices()
{
    string url = $"{baseurl}/get-offices";

    var response = await httpservices.SendGetRequest(url);

    for (int i = 0; i < response.Count; i++)
    {
        Offices.Add(new Office() { id = (string)response[i]["id"], OfficeName = (string)response[i]["office_name"] });
    }
}
```

And my XAML looks like this:

```
<CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Offices}">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="viewmodel:Office" >
            <Grid Padding="5">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Frame Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Padding="15" BackgroundColor="LightBlue" x:Name="OfficeSelection" CornerRadius="0">
                    <Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="2" RowDefinitions="Auto,Auto" ColumnDefinitions="40,*">

                        <CheckBox Grid.Column="0" x:Name="{Binding OfficeName}" CheckedChanged="OnCheckBoxCheckedChanged"/>
                        <Label TextTransform="Uppercase" Padding="10" FontSize="Default" Text="{Binding OfficeName}" Grid.Column="1"></Label>

                    </Grid>
                </Frame>

            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

And it will display like this:

[image]

What I want to do is, when I click the continue button, I can get all the checked checkboxes Name or value where in this case are: ADMISSION, CASHIER, PLENARY HALL and store it in array?

This is my button XAML:

```
<Button
Grid.Row="1"
Grid.Column="0"
Margin="5"
BorderWidth="0"
Command="{Binding GetSelectedOfficesCommand}"
CornerRadius="0"
Text="Continue" />

[RelayCommand]
public void GetSelectedOffices()
{
  //CODe HERE     
       
}
```

MAUI related MS Docs is quiet confusing for me. Anyone can give me a code snippet to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add a boolean property to the office view model and bind it to the checkbox `IsChecked`. Then in your `GetSelectedOffices` function you just filter by this property:

```
var selectedNames = Offices.Where(x => x.IsSelected).Select(x => x.OfficeName);
```

Comment: Wow! No comment. It just works :D